# Flatten Json Key, values in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In a table having 2 columns and 2 Records :

Record 1 : Column 1 -  my_col value as: `{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]}` and Column 2 - ID as `A123`

Record 2 : Column 1 -  my_col value as: `{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"], "ZZZ":["333","444"]}` and Column 2 - ID as `B222`

Need to parse/flatten using pyspark

Expectation :

| Key | Value | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 123 | A123 |
| XXX | 456 | A123 |
| YYY | 246 | A123 |
| YYY | 135 | A123 |
| ZZZ | 333 | B222 |
| ZZZ | 444 | B222 |

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your column is a string, you may use the `from_json` and `custom_schema` to convert it to a `MapType` before using `explode` to extract it into the desired results. I assumed that your initial column was named `my_col` and that your data was in a dataframe named `input_df`.

An example is shown below

#### Approach 1: Using pyspark api

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

custom_schema = T.MapType(T.StringType(),T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

output_df = (
    input_df.select(
        F.from_json(F.col('my_col'),custom_schema).alias('my_col_json')
    )
    .select(F.explode('my_col_json'))
    .select(
        F.col('key'),
        F.explode('value')
    )
)
```

#### Approach 2: Using spark sql

```py
# Step 1 : Create a temporary view that may be queried
input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_df")
# Step 2: Run the following sql on your spark session
output_df = sparkSession.sql("""
SELECT
    key,
    EXPLODE(value)
FROM (
    SELECT
        EXPLODE(from_json(my_col,"MAP<STRING,ARRAY<STRING>>"))
    FROM
        input_df
) t
""")
```

### For json column

If already json

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df = (
    input_df.select(F.explode('my_col_json'))
    .select(
        F.col('key'),
        F.explode('value')
    )
)
```

or

```py
# Step 1 : Create a temporary view that may be queried
input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_df")
# Step 2: Run the following sql on your spark session
output_df = sparkSession.sql("""
SELECT
    key,
    EXPLODE(value)
FROM (
    SELECT
        EXPLODE(my_col)
    FROM
        input_df
) t
""")
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing plenty of options, I am trying it.

Comment: How can I achieve this scenario using Hive QL  query?

Comment: You may try the SQL shared in the `spark-sql` examples shared here and let me know if those work for you.

Comment: when I am trying Approach 2 :                                                                         
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax  , pointing at MAP

Comment: when trying For json column  ---  pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'explode(table_name.`json_column`)' due to data type mismatch: 
input to function explode should be array or map type, not StringType;;\n'Project [explode(json_col#3) AS List()]\n+- SubqueryAlias 
table_name\n   +- HiveTableRelation `DB_name`.`table_name`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde

Comment: when trying For json column second option also I am getting the above error "cannot resolve explode due to data type mismatch"

Comment: from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
bank = hive_context.table("default.bank")
bank.show()                                                                                                                                          ----The above code runs in CLI producing Jason column , requirement is it need to parse/flatten

Comment: FYI:                                                                                                                              
 INPUT schema :[Column#0, Column#1, Column#2, json_column#3], [trans_dt#4]
Output schema :[Column#0, Column#1, Column#2, parse Key#3,parse value#4], [trans_dt#5]